# Svelte crossfade transition between pages

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to transition between two pages in sveltekit but this doesn't seem to work, how can I do this?

```
<!-- src/routes/asdf.svelte -->
<script>
  import { crossfade } from 'svelte/transition'
  const [send, receive] = crossfade({ })
</script>

<a href="/foo" in:receive={{ key: 'asdf' }} out:send={{ key: 'asdf' }}>Go to foo</a>
```

```
<!-- src/routes/foo.svelte -->
<script>
  import { crossfade } from 'svelte/transition'
  const [send, receive] = crossfade({})
</script>

<a href="/asdf" in:receive={{ key: 'asdf' }} out:send={{ key: 'asdf' }} style="background: crimson">Go to asdf</a>
```

Comment: Your key is identical on both pages. It should be something unique to the element so Svelte knows which one's which. Try changing the key in "foo.svelte" to "foo" instead of "asdf" and see if that changes anything. If it still doesn't work, try setting the properties of the object you're passing to the crossfade function. An example is given in the svelte tutorial: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/deferred-transitions

Comment: I've seen that tutorial but it's not across components

Comment: Also shouldn't be the same since they are the same element - I want to crossfade between the two?

Comment: There is a blog post that suggests the trick is to create the crossfade transition in its own file and import it into both pages. I will be trying this as soon as I can, I just can't right now. You're right about the key naming. They contain something different but are the same conceptual object being replaced so they should have the same key name. https://dev.to/buhrmi/svelte-component-transitions-5ie

Comment: Hmmm I swear I tried that... Will have to give it another go

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to import the same crossfade reference in each component / page

https://stackblitz.com/edit/sveltekit-sphygf?file=src/routes/index.svelte

index.svelte

```
<script>
  import {crossfade} from './crossfade'
  const [send, receive] = crossfade
</script>

<a out:send="{{key: 'a'}}" in:receive="{{key: 'a'}}"   style="border: 1px solid crimson; padding: 20px; margin-top: 20px; display: block" href="/foo">Go to foo</a>
```

foo.svelte

```
<script>
  import {crossfade} from './crossfade'
  const [send, receive] = crossfade
</script>

<a out:send="{{key: 'a'}}" in:receive="{{key: 'a'}}"  style="border: 10px solid crimson; padding: 60px; margin-top: 20px; display: block" href="/">Go to /</a>
```

crossfade.ts

```
import { crossfade as svelteCrossfade } from 'svelte/transition';

export const crossfade = svelteCrossfade({});
```

Comment: Is there any documentation about this in the docs?

Comment: There is nothing in the docs about it, but there should, this is the correct solution

Comment: I am trying to use this method utilizing route Paramus and the transition is not working. $page.Paramus.id. I can confirm the id’s match up.